# Frustrating Down-votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a down/up votes be accompanied by a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/can-a-down-up-votes-be-accompanied-by-a-comment)

I have been facing lot of trouble with the down-vote system, in the past people used to down-vote me as my english was poor, but from last two months I have been taking much care in formatting questions and asking them in a good manner, but I don't understand why did I get down-votes still without a reason.

My previous question was well in syntax but unnecessarily got a down-vote, 
I have an idea but I want an answer from Moderator, I wanted to implement a plan to change down-vote system.

The plan is as follows :

"It should be made mandatory that every down-vote should be followed with a comment, (that comment should be differentiated from others, so that user have clarity that down-vote was given for that purpose, or atleast clicking down-vote should generate a check-list with common down-vote options such as "bad-formatting, offensive language, not a real question etc.. and those should be displayed to the OP in his down-vote section, along with the number of down-votes and the cause beside).

So that the OP who posted the question will understand the reason behind getting down-votes and correct himself .

But its surely annoying if some down-voted the post without commenting, it will express the meaning that some people have grudge in them.

Comment on my proposal

Comment: Ha ha, really non-sense, its like pricking on wound, a question about down-votes got down-voted without having reason, I think this might happen only due to two things, 1) people are very timid and fearing for OP to tell his mistake, in that case I pity them, 2)Having personal grudge on people, in that case I laugh with pity for showing differences at professional level, Ok do what ever you want

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/can-a-down-up-votes-be-accompanied-by-a-comment)

Comment: Downvotes in meta perhaps only mean disagreement with the proposal. It does not necessarily reflect anything else, and you surely should not take it personally.  //  Of course, as Swapan and Mariano point out, you haven't searched the previous posts in meta, so it's possible you are downvoted because of that.

Comment: @Iyengar Don't be frustrated with the downvotes, just focus on learning math.

Answer (score 10):

This has come up before on meta. You should search a bit to see what has been said on the subject (and my guess is, the downvotes on *this* meta question are probably objecting to your not having searched for previous discussions...)

In any case, commenting when down-voting will not be made mandatory.

Comment: Ok sir, But can I know the reasons for not making it mandatory, It would be beneficial for both Op and other persons @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez

Comment: There is extensive discussion about this in the link Swapan gave you. You should really look at it.