# Can we be nicer to downvoters?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting

[I vote a lot.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) This includes quite a few downvotes. I do not comment with my downvotes anymore, because most of the time when I do comment I am met with attacks. I have been called names, received retaliation downvotes, etc. Today even, I downvoted something. In the comments there were a few people shaming the unknown downvoter.

I simply don't explain my downvotes anymore. I don't care that some stranger is upset with me. However there is [considerable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/why-is-it-that-people-down-vote-an-answer-without-even-bothering-to-comment-what) [desire](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/can-a-down-up-votes-be-accompanied-by-a-comment) [for](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/frustrating-down-votes) [explanations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/downvoting-for-no-stated-reason-is-abusive) of downvotes. I understand this. However attacking downvoters disincentives an explanations, to the point where me (and I'm sure many others) simply don't explain ever!

So if someone is kind enough to explain their downvote, do not attack them. A downvote is not a personal attack on you. A downvote is not saying that your question/answer is trash and unsalvagable or anything like that.

So, **can we please be nicer to downvoters, especially those who are kind enough to explain their downvote?**

Comment: It is a bit of a paradox, innit? Even a constructive comment becomes a lightning rod if said comment was accompanied by a downvote. It would be interesting to count how many of the people who ask for downvote explanations are also petty enough to perform retaliatory downvotes when given an explained downvote.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm at the exact same place - I've gotten quite a bit of abuse (and not just here at SE, but also off-site) as a result of giving such comments.

Comment: Maybe we should start a campaign to shame unexplained upvotes!

Comment: I thanked an unknown downvoter recently, in case that restores your faith in humankind.  Subjective "I don't like it" downvotes are a form of noise on the main site, but downvotes that lead to correction of significant mathematical errors in an answer are a free proofreading service.  The service becomes more valuable with explanatory comments but is still a service without them.

Comment: This (being nicer to downvotes) is unfortunately never going to happen. You see, downvotes take something of great value to the downvotee: 2 points of reputation. From the experiences I've had explaining my downvotes, downvoting is generally seen as casting judgment on their entire life, value as a human being, everything and finding it unsatisfactory.

Comment: I don't abuse downvoters but I do expect them to explain why they downvoted.  Why?  Because they could be wrong.  I have given an answer, with an (implicit) assurance that it is correct to the best of my ability.  Why should I believe a downvoter who is not prepared to give any kind of assurance that their disagreement is correct?

Comment: For what it's worth, there are times where downvotes are perplexing. And in those cases silent downvotes can cause a bit of emotional discomfort. Picture yourself giving a seminar talk, to a large crowd, and when you are in your third board of the proof, someone from the back of the crowd says "No, you're wrong". You can't identify who that was, and no additional input is given. How do you feel? Do you think you'll be stressed? Do you think you'll be upset? Would you feel any sort of discomfort? Not all downvotes should be explained, but sometimes... sometimes they should be.

Comment: I used to offer explanations for downvotes following comments asking for them. The reactions were more often than not negative. I once even initiated a chat room for users to ask what might be the reason for some downvote. The interest in this was minimal. I am convinced there is much less actual interest in explanations than is claimed.

Comment: @David many downvotes never intended to challenge the *correctness* of the post. It appears your expectation is based on a false premise.

Comment: All downvotes should be explained, so that the person asking has a chance to correct the problem. If the comment has already been make upvote the comment so you don't repeat yourself. Yes there can be heat from engaging someone. But the alternative is worse. If we believe there is a problem with a question. Then we are coming to a bad circumstance to begin with. I'd say a downvote is meant to be useful. If you can't explain your downvote in a comment. You should consider not downvoting at all.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez I've had several occasions now where I've tried to leave constructive comments explaining my downvotes of bad posts, and gotten abusive or even threatening emails over it. I don't mind having a little discussion with someone here on the site, but there are a lot of occasions where it develops far past that.

Comment: Most often I comment before downvoting, considerably before when I believe a possibility of correction exists.  However to give an illustration of what @quid mentions as a downvote not challenging the *correctness* of a post, I observed a new user closely copying a previous Answer on a year old Question.  The answer was correct, but...

Comment: @David: I confess, when a user thinks a question deserves a downvote but is disinclined to go through the effort of commenting and all that would entail, between the options of "cast the downvote without comment" and lying about their opinion with "don't cast the downvote", it's the *latter* I would consider intellectually dishonest.

Comment: I’m certainly not going to attack someone responsible enough to explain a downvote. I will, however, continue to make snide remarks about unexplained downvotes of correct answers, especially when they are the first vote, though I do try to remember to remove such comments once the net vote ceases to be misleading.

Comment: @hardmath: In that case a comment drawing the reader’s attention to the earlier answer is useful; a downvote isn’t.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the assumption in hardmath's scenario is, I think, that the redundant answer was likely given to get some quick points. If the goal is to avoid this being done again, a downvote can be quite useful to this end, arguably more so than a comment explaining the situation.  On your other comment, in my observation you did not always react well to valid mathematical criticism (note observation, not experience).

Comment: @quid: I really couldn’t care less about a little point-shopping, and I suspect that pointing out the copying is more effective anyway. On the other matter, I am highly skeptical of your supposed observation: I have not found your interpretation of comments here to be altogether reliable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott fine it is well known that others do care, and act accordingly. You might consider showing some consideration for the opinions and sensibilities of others.

Comment: Can we be harsher to incorrect answers? Why the hell should anyone have the expectation that their answer will not be downvoted if there are issues with it? Witness my recent experience downvoting at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814579/ to see where I'm coming from. Hell, include a clause in the FAQ that one should expect incorrect answers to be downvoted, possibly to oblivion, and even deleted. If there are disagreements about the correctness of the answer, well, that's why there's democratic voting, and also comments to be used to resolve the issues.

Comment: @Vlad, that is certainly an excellent point, but people with Dunning-Kruger (yes, I have seen them here :P) often have a hard time objectively seeing why what they wrote is crap, and are also often spiteful enough to do retaliatory downvotes. As I see it, we are prolly preaching to the choir.

Comment: Well, this happened 6 hours back in one of [my questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1835575/45937). And this question welcomes me to Meta. Pretty sure we managed scare that user away with that downvote and attention!

Comment: I posted this as an answer - and it was multiply downvoted with a suggestion that it be a comment. Here it is; answer deleted.

I never downvote. Well, very rarely, and never if there's already a downvote. I do comment in ways that I hope will improve the question or answer.

By the way, the behavior addressed in the question doesn't seem to happen (much) on the TeX stackexchange.

Comment: @Ethan: For what it's worth, comparing to other SE website is meaningless, because each website has its own subculture.

Comment: I did have my share of experiences with downvotes and those downvotes without explanations were just bogus. The answer survived because ultimately good prevails. In few cases I got downvotes with explanations and I was able to turn them into upvotes by discussion with downvoter via comments and chat. Once or twice I did get abuse because I downvoted with explanation, but I don't mind it. If a person loses an opportunity to learn it is his loss not mine.

Comment: Another forum I frequent (unrelated to stackexchange) has a Praise/Dislike feature. 'Praise' (analogous to Upvote) can be given either with your username or anonymously (upvoter's choice), and the comment accompanying the vote is optional. A 'Dislike' (analogous to Downvote) can only be given anonymously and a comment is compulsory. The user is unable to trace the source of the downvote, but if the justification is total BS, they can raise the issue to the board admin/mods, who can trace the downvote and take action. I think this is a system worth adopting (provided the software can handle it)

Comment: @Deepak: This seems to be a very good idea indeed.

Comment: @Deepak: Sounds horrible to me. Why have the option to dislike if you don't want people using it?

Comment: @Deepak: I wouldn't want to be an unpaid volunteer moderator on a site like that that has quarter of a million users. (I mean, not that I want to be a moderator here, but I'm saying that such a feature would strip all will from unpaid volunteers that put a lot of their time and effort into the site for literally nothing in return.)

Comment: @Hurkyl Why would you infer that? Keeping the downvoters anonymous  (except to the mods/admin) helps avoid retaliatory downvoting (good). Making an explanatory comment (visible to all but unattributed publicly for anonymity) compulsory helps keep downvoting honest (good). If the justification looks like total BS (or the comment field is filled with gibberish), then reporting that to the mods is justified, and (after review) that will be punished by a warning and/or docking of points to the irresponsible downvoter.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I accept your point, but no one said a moderator's job was supposed to be easy (and I have done this before). In any case, this can be handled like the review queue - have a tier of users with a certain rep cut off review reported downvote comments (the reporting is done by the user who got downvoted, so that's the first screen). They have the option to accept (downvote comment legitimate), reject (downvote comment looks like it's BS and escalated for moderator attention) or skip (beyond their expertise or not sure - maybe this will pass thru a few others before escalation).

Comment: @Deepak: If you paid any attention to meta discussions about downvotes, the high reputation users (who are active on meta) have extremely different views on downvotes. This is a recipe for disaster, widening the schism which can be found in divisive issues already existing on the site (e.g. context, closure, deletion, downvotes, etc.), and coming from a culture which is rife with division, I could do with one less in my online mathematical haven.

Comment: All I'm proposing is a structure that keeps downvoting constructive and avoids problems like serial downvoting out of spite or in retaliation. The forum that I am a member of has gone through a few iterations of changes before this system was arrived at. It's not perfect, but I feel it's better than the system currently existing here. And if even this is not acceptable, perhaps we have to ask if downvoting even has a place here. Lots of other places have no downvoting (or votes "against")- real life elections and Facebook, for instance. Perhaps there is a reason for this.

Comment: @Deepak: Every obstacle to casting a dislike means fewer 'honest' people will cast them. Exposing their opinion to ridicule means fewer honest people will cast them (anonymity doesn't help here). Opening themselves up to the risk of official censure means fewer honest people will cast them.

Comment: @Deepak: (also, I wish upvoting were kept 'honest'; downvotes are a much better indicator of things I don't want to read than upvotes are of things I do want to read)

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is no need for overdramatising the issue. It's not like there isn't already a problem with the downvoting system here - the fact that it's a contentious issue shows that at least some users are uncomfortable with it. I don't see how open discussion of how the system can be improved can be construed as increasing schism. And yes, I haven't been active on meta. But that shouldn't devalue my opinion - I have an equal stake in this site (though with less baggage?) and I am proposing the adoption (possibly with tweaks) of a system I've found fair elsewhere.

Comment: @Hurkyl How would a (publicly) unattributed explanation for a downvote expose the downvoter's opinion to ridicule? In any case, balance that against the obvious ridicule (not to mention loss of rep) that the downvote causes to the target. If the downvote is given honestly and legitimately, there's no issue, but what if it isn't?

Comment: @Deepak: I agree, there is no need for overdramatization. I am just talking from my experience on this meta.

Comment: (And by the way, if I were a moderator, seeing someone saying "tough luck, being a moderator is hard work" in the spirit of your reaction to my comment would have made me very frustrated. I'm sure that you are not an ingrate, but it comes across like that.)

Comment: @Deepak: A public but unattributed comment is still a public comment and thus exposed for the public to respond to. One doesn't need to be able to connect the comment to a specific persona in order to offer ridicule.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Obviously, I didn't mean to come across like that, and it seems you're reading too much into my remark. What I meant was that moderating is never a cake-walk - it hasn't been when I've done it (and no, I wasn't paid then either). The number of people given moderator responsibilities has to be balanced against the workload. If this additional responsibility necessitates an increase in the number of mods, then elect more! But I've already proposed an added measure (the review queue thing) that would alleviate the burden somewhat.

Comment: @Hurkyl But how is the "ridicule" arising from this comment any more preferable to the "ridicule" from a completely anonymous downvote that no one else can figure out?

Comment: @Deepak: And now we've circled back to my original criticism -- why have the option to dislike if you don't want people to receive them?

Comment: @Deepak: ... my first reaction to the opinions you've shared on this is that what you *really* want is a "report" button or "flag" button or somesuch, and **not** a feature that is the opposite of praise.

Comment: @Hurkyl It seems you're missing my point. I have no issue with keeping dislikes/downvotes, but the process must be kept honest (and therefore disliking/downvoting must be defensible). I want people who deserve downvotes to receive them, but I also want the reason for this to be clearly stated. I also want the identity of the person doing the downvoting to be kept confidential so that there is no retaliation.

Comment: @Hurkyl No, the report button will be used if the target of the downvote feels that it's an unjust downvote (BS/gibberish explanation, etc.). This will escalate the comment to the mods (who can see all parties involved).

Comment: @Deepak: And I'm saying that the implementation has consequences, and what happens in practice is not going to be the ideal you're hoping for.

Comment: @Hurkyl Fair enough, but what is ever ideal? Anyway, it's just a proposal. (BTW, hello, I know you from PF.com. I'm a HH there).

Comment: @Deepak: My main complaint with having more hoops to jump through, in addition to what Hurkyl said about making downvotes less effective, is that it piles on the bureaucracy needed from users and to be handled by other users. Would you suggest a similar feature for upvotes? If not, then just cancel downvotes altogether, and if you do, then just cancel voting altogether, because it will cause people who vote a lot to vote much much *much* less, which is not a desirable outcome under any circumstances.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have no issues with taking away the downvote feature altogether. I don't see why *all* voting needs to be cancelled. There seems to be at least one non-sequitur in your comment. If someone thinks there's something wrong with a question or answer either do nothing or just leave a constructive comment. If he thinks it contributes positively to the site, upvote it. Taking away downvotes doesn't take away a whole lot from the site, in my opinion.

Comment: @Deepak: But what about upvote abuse? You ask your friends to vote you up, you ask your students to vote you up, you like someone and just vote them up. And you do all this without needing to justify anything. And that happened in the past, on very large scales, too. Downvotes are a means to an end. They allow a user to quickly determine that something might not be worth reading, without sifting through endless comments "I like it" and "I don't like it". On a site this big, that is not a bad thing to have. So if you want to cancel downvotes, you can't keep upvotes, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: (And just to clarify the last sentence of my last comment, this is my private and personal opinion. And since there is no objective truth anyway, I don't see how this can be misconstrued as claiming anything is "a sound and objective reason". I have developed my opinion over the last six years or so that I have been an active member of this community. Your mileage may vary, and your opinions may differ based on your own personal upbringing, cultural background, brain chemistry, current blood glucose levels, and many other factors which depend on your current and past 4D coordinates.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't consider upvote abuse because it's not a factor for me (in all honesty). I have no "IRL" friends here and I don't teach math (formally), I am an enthusiastic amateur. So I didn't consider it. I defer to your experience and accept that this can happen, and in fact, has happened before. I am curious though - how was upvote abuse ever actually discovered? I don't think the "target" is the one reporting it. Are the mods being hypervigilant in surveilling the site or are they responding to third party reports based on suspicion?

Comment: (and btw, my psychosocial, biochemical and spatiotemporal characteristics are just fine, thanks for wondering) :)

Comment: @Deepak: That's a story for another time. But suffice to say, you can suddenly notice that someone who wasn't garnering a lot of reputation suddenly has a lot more. Or that some few people repeatedly show up in comments of each other and stroke each other's ego "a bit too much". These raise red flag with some people, who raise actual flags to the moderators, who investigate these things, and either suspend/delete accounts or push these issues higher up to the SE overlords. You can find users, if you look hard enough, that had several thousands points removed as "voting corrections".

Comment: @AsafKaragila The reason I'm asking is not just idle curiosity but because it ties in to our discussion on the burden placed on the mods (you implied it was already too onerous to expect then to review flagged downvote comments). I would expect the detection of "upvote rings" to be a fiendishly difficult task to do "by eye and hand". Unless there is clever automation built in, perhaps the mods (prompted by other motivated users, who can view the comments, after all) do have capacity to take care of moderating flagged downvotes.

Comment: @Deepak: You'd be surprised what one can deduce with just a lot of patience and connecting the publicly available dots. Sure, it's not solid evidence, but sometimes it's enough to raise a sufficient alarm and to push this up the chain. There are also some automated tools, which I know very little about, as I never was a moderator. But it is a known fact that some automated tools exist, and that if you are patient enough, and careful enough, you can probably circumvent them, if you really want to.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, thank you. This was an interesting discussion.

Comment: @Deepak Asaf is correct about said large upvoting ring (which led to many suspensions). It was discovered partly because one user bragged about it on meta, and partly  because many patterns were clear (every day the vote farmers received a string of 3-5 upvotes only seconds apart, a pattern which repeated over a year or more).  Mods and SE staff have tools which can assist in revealing such patterns.

Comment: Rather than down vote, I suggest you leave a constructive comment that alerts the one who posted the answer as to your concern.  This gives the author a chance to improve her/his answer before being penalized.  I hope that you and all of the other "happy trigger" down voters consider this courtesy.  Put yourself in the other person's situation.  Would you not appreciate the opportunity to address the concern and improve an answer before you were punished for trying to help someone.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV And how does that help deal with the issue at hand (downvoters are attacked when they explain their downvotes)?

Comment: Zach, the remedy is to refrain from issuing a down vote until one has given the author a fair chance to address a concern.  It is uncivil to do otherwise and discourages those who are trying to offer sincere help.  Empathy is the key here.

Comment: @Dr.MV those who think of themselves as offering "sincere help" can also be problem when they expect the sincerity to offset the fact that the help they offer either is garbage or people think that it is garbage.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I agree.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I think it's important to distinguish between "garbage" and "slightly wrong". In the former case, I think a DV is totally justified. In the latter, a comment without a DV is the civil thing to do. Yet, I have seen people quick to vote down for minor errors and only reverse the downvote after a correction has been made (sometimes a reversal is not done or not even possible).

Comment: And sometimes, the DV is not even for an error. It's given, for instance, in cases where someone gave a full (and correct) answer when the asker didn't show working. I know that we want to discourage the asker's behaviour, but I don't think penalising those who answer questions with a DV is the solution at all.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the conception of downvotes as "penalties", or I guess reversely of upvotes as "rewards". The purpose of the score on your answer (or question) is to indicate the trust the community has in your answer, or more generally, to indicate the merit of your answer as judged by the community. Plus, there is NOTHING we can do to enforce a specific downvoting behavior, but we could do something to enforce specific commenting behavior, e.g. we could curb abuse...

Comment: @Deepak the downvote wants to discourage the answerers (not the askers) behavior in this case.

Comment: @quid And I don't agree that this is the way to go about it. For one thing, it's petty and vindictive to penalise someone who sincerely took the effort to answer a question, even if it's misguided by someone else's reckoning. For another, it's highly arbitrary which "full answer" gets downvoted and which doesn't. Some may even be upvoted, it's just the luck of the draw as to how a given user views this sort of thing. And finally, it can be confusing when a correct answer is downvoted, especially without explanation. Is the casual user supposed to infer that the answer is wrong?

Comment: @quid Ultimately, isn't this supposed to be a Q&A site? As opposed to a homework help site? I am a member of another forum that helps people (gratis) with homework, and they have strict rules strictly enforced that prevent people from answering questions where the asker shows no effort. The answer is simply deleted in that case. If that's the way Math.SE wishes to go, then perhaps that's what needs to be done. But how does that square with a site that allows people to ask questions and even award "bounties" which will incentivise answerers?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov You may disagree, but that seems to be a widely held perception, at least among lower rep users working their way upward. And really, that viewpoint is not without merit. It's not like downvotes have zero consequence - accumulate enough and you start losing privileges. It's much like points on a driving licence, accrue enough and you lose the ability to drive. Surely, no one is going to think that's not a penalty? (also, please tag me when replying, I didn't get a notification of your reply).

Comment: @Deepak whatever your opinion, it is unhelpful to the discussion to misrepresent the intent of others.

Comment: @quid I don't believe I've done that anywhere here. In point of fact, the *murkiness* of intent of a downvote without a comment is exactly what I was complaining about.

Comment: @Deepak of course you did. You said "I know that we want to discourage the asker's behaviour," (with the downvote on the answer).

Comment: @quid How is that false or a misrepresentation? That's the whole point of the "off topic" reporting when insufficient effort is shown, isn't it? What exactly is that feature for if not to discourage askers who don't show sufficient thought/effort?

Comment: @Deepak it is false in that the downvote on the answer is often specifically intended as a message to the answerer *not the asker* (which is what you claimed).

Comment: @quid Anyway, it appears you were confused by my phrasing. I did not imply that the DV on the *answer* was meant to directly penalise the *asker*. I am not sure why you derived that inference. I simply intended this as a general observation of what we wish to promote/discourage on this site. It's not totally unlinked - there would have been no DV on a correct answer if the asker had shown effort. Downvoting the question and putting it on hold is to discourage the asker. Downvoting the answer is to discourage the answerer of such a question. It is the second part I do not agree with. Clearer?

Comment: @Deepak I derived it because you wrote "It's given, for instance, in cases where someone gave a full (and correct) answer when the asker didn't show working. I know that we want to discourage the asker's behaviour, but I don't think penalising those who answer questions with a DV is the solution at all." This juxtaposition makes a clear connection between the downvote on the answer and discouraging the asker. Your  new formulation is not quite clear either.  "It is the second part I do not agree with." But I take it you don't agree with the action, and agree that this is indeed the motive.

Comment: @quid Yes, that's it in a nutshell. I don't agree with DVs for completely correct answers. In fact the behaviour guidelines quoted below prescribed DV for *misinformation*. A correct answer is *not* misinformation. Now I concede that the guideline never stipulated that that is the only circumstance where a DV can be given, but that brings us back to my complaint of arbitariness. Different people will DV for different reasons, not all of them good ones. Where is the standardisation? How is the system kept honest when these are anonymous to the users being downvoted and there is no comment left?

Comment: I feel like downvoting this post would be ironically funny... but I won't do it...

Comment: Definitely we should be nice to those who explain their down-votes.  Unexplained down-votes are worthless because they are incomprehensible: At most one can _guess_ why something was down-votes and the guesses must usually be wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: Similarly, unexplained upvotes are worthless because they are incomprehensible: At most one can *guess* why something was up-votes [sic] and the guesses must usually be wrong.

Comment: I hardly ever down-vote anything, and I try to remember to explain my objections when I do.  I've never been abused for explaining a down-vote, as far as I recall, although I think I've been disagreed with.  I have been abused for suggesting we should not be so hard on newbies. $\qquad$

Comment: From now on, all my future post will include "downvotes with explanation are welcome. so please do leave an explanation" :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It disappoints me that the admission

> I don't explain my downvotes anymore because I get abused when I do so.

and the subsequent plea

> Can you all be nicer to downvoters so that we don't feel disinclined to explain our downvotes?

is responded to with discussions of

> When, how, and why you should explain your downvotes or should you even cast downvotes at all/it's understandable why the abuse happens, how would you like it if your answer was downvoted, especially without a comment?

What I'd like to see discussed instead are

1. the transparency and facility of the mechanisms by which such abuse can be reported and appropriately dealt with.
2. whether we should and how we could modify the expectation some users have that their answers should not be downvoted, which breeds the above abuse when downvoting occurs.

My position is that the purpose of this web-site is to generate correct answers to people's questions, not to give people the opportunity to puff themselves up on reputation. The abuse impeded that and therefore I am against it, whereas the voting mechanism (both up and down) serves to assess the relative merit of the answers according to the community, and therefore I support both downvotes and commenting that improves answers. It is up to an answer's author to ensure their answer is as <del>correct</del> useful and correct as possible, especially when given feedback; abuse is unacceptable.

---

Apparently nobody reads the existing [behavior guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). The *very first guideline*, quoted below (and bolded by me) directly explains when to downvote, in direct conflict with the tenor of all the existing discussion in the comment threads of this question and its answers.

> Be honest.
>
> Above all, be honest. **If you see misinformation, [vote it down](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Add [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) indicating what, specifically, is wrong.** Provide better answers of your own. Last but not least, [edit and improve](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) the existing questions and answers! By doing these things, you are helping keep Stack Exchange a great place to share knowledge of our craft.
>
> While you’re doing all of those things, we also require that you...

Ah, but maybe they do, it's just that they follow the link to the [privilege documentation on downvoting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), and don't just stick to the behavior guideline.

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
>
> ...
>
> Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.
>
> Instead of voting down:
>
> - If the post is spammy or offensive, [**flag** it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
> - If the question is duplicate or off-topic, [**flag** it for moderator attention](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
> - If something is wrong, please [leave a **comment**](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) or [**edit** the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to correct it.

**Why are these in contradiction to one another??!!!**

The guideline suggests to always vote misinformation down, while the privilege documentation suggests that downvoting should be an action of last resort in improving a question or answer. I'd wager much of the abuse to downvoters stems from users believing in the privilege documentation and not the behavior guideline, while many of the downvoters believe in the guideline and not the documentation.

Obviously *abuse* is never justified, but the *outrage* of being downvoted would be justified by the way the downvoting privilege is described. I think this flaw in the documentation should be taken up to meta.stackexchange.com...

---

I *also* don't read the guidelines, otherwise I will have known that there *already are* well-written instructions on [dealing with abuse](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) by [flagging](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/flagging). Specifically

> Don't be a jerk. These are just a few examples. If you see them, [flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) them:
>
> - **Name-calling.** Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").
> - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a *few examples*; when in doubt, just don't.)
> - **Inappropriate language or attention.** Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is *not* a dating site.
> - **Harassment and bullying.** If you see a hostile interaction, [flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) it. If it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff attention, you can use the [contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: "It is up to an answer's author to ensure their answer is as correct as possible..."

Actually, it is up to the answer's author to ensure that an answer is as *useful* as possible.  Correctness does not imply any level of usefulness to either the OP or the community.

Comment: i'd agree that correctness is only necessary, not sufficient.

Comment: There are arguments that correctness and usefulness are somewhat independent of each other. There can be useful threads which include very common "naive approach" and though these approaches may often fail, that *is* useful, even if not correct.

Comment: if you're suggesting it's good enough to have useful incorrect answers, i disagree: it's better to have useful correct answers (of course "correct" can be understood broadly: with errors or pitfalls clearly labeled, etc). if we were to belabor the point i'd say that usefulness is the degree to which an answer actually answers the question, i.e., "generate correct answers *to* people's questions"... but let's not belabor the point.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that the abuse goes both ways. No, downvoters should not be abused simply for downvoting. But the fact is that some downvotes are at best displays of ignorance and at worst abusive; I’ve seen two such in the last hour.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Downvotes on their own (unless given overwhelmingly or serially, which is usually reversed automatically) are not abusive. They may not be friendly or nice, but the worst they do is cost a few reputation points from every party involved. This is incomparable with the abuse that those who are willing to comment about downvotes receive.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Reputation is almost irrelevant, save for new answerers. When the first vote on a correct answer is a downvote, that downvote is definitely abusive: it is misleading to the OP and any casual reader, and it may cause the answerer to waste time trying to figure out whether there actually is an error, and if so, what it is. The more upvotes there are, the less the downvote matters.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I was serially downvoted, several times, by people who know the script limitations, and just dowvoted one or two posts a day for a while. This sort of behavior takes a long time to discover and recover, and it *is* frustrating. Because I put, usually, *a lot* of effort into my answers. So this means some period of annoyance, before there is some enough evidence. And as time progresses, whoever is behind this becomes cleverer and this becomes more difficult to detect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if you insist labeling commentless downvoting as abuse, it is obviously an abuse of a *different kind* than the abuse that a downvoter also receives (verbal attacks, shaming, stalking, etc). These two different kinds of abuse would have to be addressed by different mechanisms so I don't think conflating them is useful toward resolving either issue.

Comment: Also, is it not obvious that downvoting itself would not be abolished, that decorating downvotes with comments would not be mandated, hence that the commentless downvoting "abuse" can be limited a) by the algorithms to detect it, and b) establishing community norms to retaliate with verbal abuse, etc. or c) I can't think of a "c)".

Comment: @Vladimir: I am not conflating them. I'm afraid that I can't make sense of your second comment, so I can't respond to it.

Comment: I meant that, short of instituting a community guideline to berate anonymous downvotes (which is absurd, i don't mean anyone's suggesting it), there isn't much we can do to curb anonymous downvotes beyond the curbing already done by the algorithms to prevent serial downvoting and such. On the other hand, I think there is something the community can do to decrease the verbal abuse and such that's heaped on downvoters. That's why I think even labeling downvoting itself as an "abuse" conflates it with the (in my opinion), more serious but also more easily tractable kind of abuse that's verbal, &c

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If the sentence "You seem to be ignoring the fact that the abuse goes both ways." (your own words) isn't conflating the two kinds of abuse, I don't know what is.

Comment: Rather than down vote, I suggest one leave a constructive comment that alerts the one who posted the answer as to your concern.  This gives the author a chance to improve her/his answer before being penalized.  I hope that all of the "happy trigger" down voters consider this courtesy.  They should put themselves in the other person's situation.  Would they not appreciate the opportunity to address the concern and improve an answer before being punished for trying to help someone.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV, that's my usual modus, but it happens that there are people who are... intransigent, and I am then inclined to downvote when my comments have not been at least taken into consideration. More pressingly, however: this place is starting to feel like SO, and I'm not sure I like it at all.

Comment: maybe if we're more abusive to commenters who contribute only noise, they will stop commenting! let me try: @Dr.MV do you not see that your comment is completely inappropriate for *this* thread because the very answer the thread's subordinate to is about how off-topic discussions of "how to downvote" are? do you not read what others write because you assume that your own opinions are so novel and brilliant that there is no way they've been thought of or discussed at all in the hundreds(!) of comments throughout the discussion of this question?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Yes.   How's that?  And your comment has been flagged as rude and offensive.  ;-))

Answer (score 27):

This question is the logical equivalent of "Can we be nicer to the tax collector?"  We certainly need the tax collector so that we may function as a society.  Without the tax collector, we lose the ability to govern ourselves.  Yet, when the tax collector calls us, do we thank him/her?

**ADDENDUM**

Along these lines, perhaps we can take some cues from the litany of wannabe Presidents of the United States:

- Bernie Sanders: Only the Top 1% in reputation may be downvoted, and they should be downvoted with impunity.
- Ted Cruz: Everyone should have 15% of their posts downvoted, across the board.
- Donald Trump: I have a terrific plan to make everyone happy with downvoting, it's terrific, it's great, you'll see soon.

Comment: Thanks for the analogy, I needed a good laugh today. :D

Comment: @J.M.: Research shows that you need a good laugh *every* day.

Comment: @Asaf, I'm well aware, but I haven't really been getting it lately. That's why I thought it important to show appreciation for sources of laughter.

Comment: @J.M.: Then it's time to watch Blackadder again. Preferably seasons 2 and 3. But also the Millennium special. Or, just any Monty Python thing.

Comment: I believe there's a middle ground between thanking and hurling insults. Would you be okay with someone sending a letter filled with insults to the collector's home address?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: No, I would not.  That wasn't my point however, which is that downvoting is an essential part of our knowledge base, except nobody wants to suffer it individually.

Comment: Well, maybe I misinterpreted your post, but the OP is asking "please do not attack the downvoter" and you reply "well we don't thank the tax collector do we?". This makes it sound like personally attacking a downvoter is on the same level as not thanking the tax collector... All I'm saying is that your point could have been phrase better (e.g. as in your last comment).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I think you took my post a little too literally - it was meant to be tongue-in-cheek. I am perfectly OK with my phrasing.  Saying we don't exactly thank the tax collector is an extreme understatement - we fear and loathe the tax collector, just as we fear and loathe the downvoter.

Comment: Okay, I fear it's one of these cases where humor doesn't translate well over text (unless you really mean that we fear and loathe the tax collector, in which case I don't really know what to say).

Comment: If you ever get a notice in the mail that your taxes were miscomputed and you owe $10K, tell me what feelings you have at that moment in time.  Safety and love likely are not two of them.

Comment: While I laughed at the Trump commentary, I feel that we have enough politics as it is. No need to introduce outside poison.

Comment: Indeed, this addendum does not bring much of interest, if anything, to this answer.

Comment: @RonGordon i think your joke masks the fact that people who dislike their answers downvoted have literally no other justification other than their own fragile little egos getting bruised, while people's dislike of taxation is more readily justified by the threat it poses to their literal livelihood.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov: while you are on the whole correct (I never claimed that the analogy was perfect), there are users here for whom a downvote is the apparent equivalent of taking away one's livelihood.  Did knows of whom I speak.

Comment: i'll rephrase my point then: your joke equivocates receiving downvotes with having your survival threatened, and therefore tacitly endorses retaliation for downvoting. it's not a matter of the analogy being imperfect, it's a matter of it being actively misleading. the fact that for some people receiving downvotes does feel life-threatening is a part of the (also important) "when should we downvote?" discussion, not this "how do we not abuse downvoters?" discussion.

Comment: *Yet, when the tax collector calls us, do we thank him/her?* — **Yes, we should.**

Comment: @gerrit, yet you should know well that theory and practice do not often match... ;)

Comment: Ron, I cannot stop laughing at this!  Rather than down vote, I suggest one leave a constructive comment that alerts the one who posted the answer as to your concern.  This gives the author a chance to improve her/his answer before being penalized.  I hope that all of the "happy trigger" down voters consider this courtesy.  They should put themselves in the other person's situation.  Would they not appreciate the opportunity to address the concern and improve an answer before being punished for trying to help someone.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV, it's not usually a good idea to be posting the same comment across four different comment threads, FYI.

Comment: Ron, I was communicating with different users and wanted to deliver a similar message.

Comment: @Dr. MV: Nonetheless, it's a bit annoying to find you engaging with the same comment all across the page. It feels like a five year old kid who just really want people to hear him, so he goes and says the same thing to everyone in the room, regardless to what conversation took place before.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I did not write that comment.

Comment: I've often had to remind Money.SE members that the IRS (the US tax authority) is just a collector, it's our congress that writes the tax code. But your anology is great.

Answer (score 14):

This is just a comment too long to be a comment. Judging from the above comments and the linked threads, I don't know how well this will be received. I might even get downvotes :)

Yes we probably and hopefully *can* and definitely *should* be nicer to each other in many ways. But as commented above, I don't think this is going to happen any time soon. I welcome the encouragement made here to be nicer, but I wonder how many will actually see it and act on it.

Related to the question to whether we should be nicer is the question about whether or not to comment with a downvote. I wanted to share my general approach to downvoting answers:

1. I see an answer that has a problem. If the problem is that it is SPAM, rude, or offensive, I downvote and flag it. I do not leave a comment.
2. If the answer contains a mistake, I comment asking about this. If no response is given and the mistake is not corrected I might downvote if the mistake is substantial enough.
3. Answers that I downvote always deserve a comment. Often another comment has already been made and in that case I don't leave a new comment, but I upvote the comment and downvote the answer.  If no comment exists, I comment. I have received revenge downvotes for this (at least I am pretty cure that I have) and I have learnt to just ignore this. '
4. When I do downvote, I try (and often fail) to go back later and undo the downvote if the problem is corrected.

<strike>5. Oh... and I never downvote competing answers! (In fact, it should be made impossible to downvote competing answers)</strike>

I feel strongly that a downvote on an answer that isn't spam, offensive, or rude, should be accompanied by a comment. In fact, I wouldn't mind (nor would I actively campaign for it) forcing people to comment when they downvote. The purpose of a downvote is to show the community that there is a problem with the answer. And so I think it is appropriate to explain to the author what the problem is so that it (ideally) can be worked out.

In rare cases I have actually downvoted and commented only to learn that my downvote was unjustified because I was wrong. The only way I learned this was because I commented.

EDIT: I also wanted to add that if you ever find a mistake or other reason to downvote an answer of mine, then please write a comment first. I am always grateful for any help in improving my answers.

Comment: "And so I think it is appropriate to explain to the author what the problem is so that it (ideally) can be worked out." There are authors that have been explained, and have ignored, the about same thing numerous times as they created numerous posts suffering the same problem. What's the point of doing it again and again and again?

Comment: @quid: Maybe I should have included that I don't believe that any perfect strategy exists. No matter what approach you take, you can find exceptions where another strategy work fit better. The above is my *general* strategy. I do, however, try to stay true to it by just commenting and not worrying too much about how much time it took me to comment. So what if I have to post the "same comment" to the same user several times?

Comment: I mostly agree with your approach, including often failing at 4 despite best intentions. But personally I disagree with 5. When I see an incorrect answer, downvoting that is beneficial to the site. I'd consider a spectrum from “this answer is wrong, read mine instead” through “I've got a different approach, compare for yourself” up to “this answer is great, but I'd still like to add a different perspective in my own answer” which can be nicely modeled by appropriately voting on competing answers. So imho it should be important not to downvote an answer *just because* it is competing.

Comment: For one thing, it might annoy the author more than just the downvote. In that sense one could consider it as more effective to comment, though in a sense *quite* different from the one frequently put forward. To repeat what I said in a comment on OP, many a user does not really want an explication for the downvote.

Comment: I would vote in favor of forcing a comment with every downvote. At least in a trial basis. And I do understand the frustration of getting unwanted attacks. But that is just the nature of an open website like SO. We do the best we can, and hope there are enough of us doing it to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez This idea has been shot down. Every. Single. Time. [An example.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3153/10014)

Comment: @MvG: let me strike point 5. I guess my strategy on commenting doesn't need it.

Comment: Taking the extra effort to offer a comment whenever you think a question deserves a downvote is, imo, laudable. Not downvoting when you think a question deserves one but you're disinclined to comment is, imo, shameful. I can't tell which category you fall into!

Comment: @Hurkyl: I downvote when there is a reason to downvote. If I come across a question that deserves a downvote, then I vote down. It is that simple. I just also add a comment (or upvote an existing comment.)

Comment: @Hurkyl: Suppose that someone posts an answer which is incorrect, and in an unhelpful way (there is some fundamental mistake). You can point out the mistake, and the author will *learn* from the comment, and either correct or delete the answer (or perhaps make it a CW post, with a notice that this might be an obvious mistake, and the answer is left as a "warning"). Downvoting in this situation is really unnecessary. I had several situations where I received silent downvotes on such answers, and in all of them, if I recall correctly, the answer was angrily deleted. Even if there was a comment.

Comment: Thank you. I find downvotes useless and simply don’t downvote: as a reader of the site I find the vote counts largely useless, and as an answerer I find unexplained downvotes utterly unhelpful. If there’s a problem, I leave a comment (and try to remember to check whether the problem gets fixed, so that I can delete the comment). For those who do find them useful, your approach is precisely what I’d recommend and the only one that I consider responsible and genuinely helpful.

Comment: On your point 4: It would be nice to find all posts which were changed after you downvoted them. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible with data explorer, since the user ID of votes is invisible even if it is you who voted.

Comment: @celtschk: I think this is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

To me, there are to ways of solving this; stopping the output or stopping the input, respectively:

- creating a system to punish those who threaten/attack/revenge-downvote down voters.

  - The problem with this is that it is hard to prove that someone did this
- creating a way to leave an anonymous explanation comment that still makes it possible to ping the downvoter and let the downvoter reply

I think we should implement a system similar to the second solution.

This is a problem for everybody across stack exchange communities. I propose we migrate this questions to stack exchange meta.

Comment: The technical proposal you make was in variations made dozens of times. If you really want, propose it on [meta.se]. But I'd predict it will be dupe-closed in less than an hour.

Comment: As quid said, this has already been suggested on meta.SE: [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting). And [among the linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6521) you can find some duplicates or close duplicates.

Comment: If there's a downvote and a comment pointing out a problem, there is no way to know whether the comment and the downvote are done by the same person, unless the commenter explicitly says so.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, anonymous comments would only be available to downvoters/have a "downvoted" preifx/suffix.

Comment: Rather than down vote, I suggest one leave a constructive comment that alerts the one who posted the answer as to your concern.  This gives the author a chance to improve her/his answer before being penalized.  I hope that all of the "happy trigger" down voters consider this courtesy.  They should put themselves in the other person's situation.  Would they not appreciate the opportunity to address the concern and improve an answer before being punished for trying to help someone.  -Mark

Answer (score 7):

The following is a draft wiki to hammer out guidelines for both downvoters and downvotees, concerning "being nice to downvoters" (that is, best practice for rections when receiving downvotes and coping with perceived abuse for casting downvotes), to be included in the FAQ (or wherever we decide it should go). Feel free to add relevant information or queries/suggestions for relevant information that should be included. Some of this might already be in the FAQ, but the site-navigation is sufficiently cumbersome for me not to want to do this by myself.

### DRAFT

---

Steps to take if you receive a downvote

1. If there is no comment with the downvote, take a deep breath. Take this as an opportunity to look at your answer again and improve it if it is not as correct or as clear as **you** would like it to be. Since you have no written feedback, that is the most productive course of action you can take. Do NOT decrease the quality of your answer by commenting negatively on the anonymous downvote, but feel free to politely request the downvoter comment.
2. If there is a comment explaining the reason for the downvote, you can either

   - incorporate its suggestion in your own answer if it convinces you there is a problem with your answer. If the problem with your answer is insurmountable, you should edit it to indicate the problem.
   - ignore the suggestion if its obviously incorrect, but do attempt to explain (in the comments or in your answer if appropriate) why the suggestion is incorrect. it in a comment of your own if the reasoning is incorrect.
   - if the feedback is unclear, engage in polite dialogue with the downvoter to determine the nature of the complaint. Feel free to ask them for help if they convince you there is something wrong with your answer but you are uncertain how to fix it.
   - do NOT hurl invective at the downvoter no matter how horribly incorrect you think their suggestion is or how mistaken you think they are in their understanding.

---

Steps to take if you are suffering abuse for using the downvoting mechanism, or generally for your participation on the site.

1. If you receive abusive comments, flag them as abusive. What will happen is that a moderator will evaluate whether the comment is indeed abusive, and delete it if necessary. Your moderators are:...

   - What if the abusive comment is from a moderator or high-reputation user?
2. If you receive abusive emails, contact the community managers. These are:...

Comment: Your answer mainly focuses on the downvoting of an answer. What about the downvoting of a question?

Comment: Feel free to add a section on what to do if your question is downvoted; I haven't thought about it.

Comment: Doesn't one need some number of points to flag comments as abusive?

Comment: this is a draft: fill in the details and fix the errors if you've the time and inclination...

Comment: I would take out "Do NOT decrease the quality of your answer by commenting on the anonymous downvote." If I don't get a comment on a downvote, I will often add a comment asking" Why the downvote? This has then prompted the downvoter to ad a comment. I don't see a problem in asking for clarification on a downvote.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, but so does casting a downvote. (Also it is only 15 points.) Since the latter needs more points than the former there is no problem in the current context (except in very unlikely corner cases).

Comment: Rather than down vote, I suggest one leave a constructive comment that alerts the one who posted the answer as to your concern.  This gives the author a chance to improve her/his answer before being penalized.  I hope that all of the "happy trigger" down voters consider this courtesy.  They should put themselves in the other person's situation.  Would they not appreciate the opportunity to address the concern and improve an answer before being punished for trying to help someone.  -Mark

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to draft a wiki. What's missing is that **Not all downvotes are about math errors**. They are more about the downvoter expressing their opinion that this post simply should not have been posted. Period. May be they feel that the site would be better off without the question that spawned this answer? May be they feel (or know from past dealings with this person) that the poster is so confused that the post is unsalvageable? I dare not even guesstimate how large a fraction of all our downvotes are motivated by such concerns, but it is not insignificant.

Comment: @Jyrki maybe it's not clear from what I wrote, but it was my intention to indicate that if a poster receives a downvote and, as far as they can tell, there is nothing mathematically wrong with their answer, i.e. the downvote expresses some sort of disagreement or opinion, then there's nothing for the poster to do (unless the downvote fits into a pattern of serial abuse, in which case a moderator should be flagged).

Answer (score 4):

One small step towards being nicer to downvoters would be to try to eradicate the many comments on the site to the effect of

> @downvoter: Why you downvote?

or, more colorfully,

> @downvoter: What the hell is this downvote for? explain yourself!

These probably *all* fall under the umbrella of "non-constructive". These comments are rarely answered, and so they simply become lasting noise on the site. Such comments left by old-hats also seem to embolden newer contributors to be more aggressive towards (anonymous) downvoters.

They also don't appear to serve the intended purpose of comments, as per the ["Comment Everywhere" privilege page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

(Asking about a downvote does not request clarification **from** the author, and doesn't provide constructive criticism **to** the author, and doesn't provide any additional information to the post.)

I'm not going to be holding my breath on this, as it seems that [the most frequent "downvoter" commenter is a moderator](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/518837/most-frequent-downvoter-commenters).

Comment: I flag such comments 'not constructive' as I come across them. Usually, they get deleted. To be more precise, I flag the comment typically if it reads more like a complaint; if it sincerely seeks to understand a potential problem, I might offer my opinion on that even if it is not my vote or just move on.

Answer (score -6):

Since we freely can wote as we which having enough privileges, we have to accept downvotes as we must accept weather or something. Votes is an objective messure of popularity, mainly based on the confidence in a user. And that's it!

Obviously some downvotes are obscure while most of them are adequate.

Comment: See? No hard feelings, in spite of the #@*%! downvotes.

Answer (score -20):

Don't know if it has already been proposed. Anyway, why don't force comment on downvote?
In other words, if I click "downvote", then I must obliged to write a comment. No wish to comment, no downvote. I think this is easy and effective, doesn't it?

Comment: It was proposed [in this very thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23486/can-we-be-nicer-to-downvoters/23490#comment93977_23490) and numerous times before.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution to the problem of "downvoters are being harassed due to commenting about their votes." It's literally the exact opposite of a solution. It also leads to massive amounts of unnecessary noise.

Comment: Here's my comment.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and has been discussed at length anyway.

Comment: I wanted to make the same comment as @Joel, but he already made that comment. Since I have to write a comment, this is my comment.

Comment: As mentioned by quid, this was discussed several times. Some questions discussing this were linked directly in the question.

Comment: I had only wanted to upvote Joel's and Asaf's comments, but alright, here is a comment.

Comment: @the_candyman In case you didn't understand, the comments of Joel, Asaf and J. M. are all comments that accompanied a downvote. They forced themselves to write a comment when they downvoted, as you were suggesting. As you can see, this wasn't useful at all. (Oh and this comment is accompanying a downvote too.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi ok, I got it

Comment: Eh.  Y'all seem to be having fun downvoting this one, but the non-useful comments intended to show how comments can be non-useful as self-fulfilling evidence for downvotes to this answer here looks like something of a circular argument to me.  Not saying I necessarily agree or disagree with the proposal, but unfortunately many of the dissents at this point are amounting to circular noise.  I'm +1ing this to try to balance it out and invite meaningful responses instead.  (A couple of responses, e.g. by quid, T.Bongers, and Martin. Sleziak, are indeed meaninfgul.)

Comment: @DonHatch I think you missed the point. I for example was ready to downvote without commenting because I disagree with the proposal, but if I was forced to leave a comment I would just have left a BS comment like the others.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: yes, but then, as the abused and downvoted, I'd be able to see that you downvoted me.  And then...and then...I'LL HAVE MY REVENGE!!! BWAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!...<cough cough> I mean, you'll think twice before doing the right thing regarding my lousy post.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I get that point, thanks.  Did you get mine?  I'll try again-- the BS comments accompanying downvotes for this particular question aren't credible as evidence since they are biased by the fact that they are coming from people who already don't like the proposal and are therefore motivated to produce such evidence.  Playing that card on this one doesn't help advance the position, and isn't clever, it just comes off as smug and annoying, to me.  Better to just say something like "it leads to massive amounts of unnecessary noise" (which may in fact be true) like Bonger did.

Comment: @Don: Those people also happen to downvote on a regular basis. I don't think that someone who downvotes once every blue moon will be bothered to leave a comment on that rare occasion.

Comment: @Don, for context: I'm more likely to leave a comment than downvote, but if everything I wanted to say has been said already, then I see no point in having to say those things all over again, and just vote accordingly. **I don't care for being forced to leave noise**.

Comment: @j.M  I wrote a reply along the lines of "you're not forced; you could not leave the downvote instead"... but I deleted it because see your point, if what you'd say has been said already then saying it again doesn't add value.